# HTML Helper to query database data for a given id (MVC 2 .Net C#)

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that contains a list of items. I loop through those items and then I need to return another list based on the item.id from MS SQL.

What is the based way to perform this with custom HTML Helper.

```
<table width="100%">
 <%foreach(var item in Model.BlogList) %> 
        <%{ %>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <%: Html.ActionLink(item.title, "GetBlog", new { id = item.id, name = item.title }, null)%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <hr />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date: 
        <%= Convert.ToDateTime(item.createdDate).ToShortDateString() %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Posted By: 
        <%= item.postedBy %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class='blog_post'><%= item.body %></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Tags: HERE IS WHERE I need to return a new list based on item.id  (I would need a new SQL SELECT)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refactor your model so that it includes the data needed by the view.  Typically, you'd construct a view-specific model containing the data.  This model can "roll up" data from various domain models to encapsulate the data needed by the view.

For example:

```
public class BlogViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public sring Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string PostedBy { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TagViewMOdel> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagViewModel
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your action (assuming you have an entity relationship between blogs and tags).

```
var model = this.Context
                .Blogs
                .Select( b => new BlogViewModel {
                    b.ID,
                    b.Name,
                    b.CreatedDate,
                    PostedBy = b.Author.Name,
                    b.Body,
                    Tags = b.BlogTags
                            .SelectMany( bt => bt.Tags )
                            .Select( t => new TagViewModel { t.Tag, t.ID } )
                            .ToList()
                 })
                .ToList();
```

Then you have all the data you need without having to involve the data context or perform another DB query.

```
<tr>           
    <td><% foreach (var tag in item.Tags) { %>
           <%= Html.ActionLink( tag.Tag, "tag", "search", new { id = tag.ID }, null %>
        <% } %>          
    </td>           
</tr>
```

Comment: Table: Blogs

BlogId 
title

Table: BlogTags

blogId 
tagId

Table: Tags

TagId 
TagName

Comment: That is my table structure, Does this still apply as you are selecting on the Tag table directly instead of going to BlogTags first to find the tagid's that are needed.

Comment: @RPS - the point would be to extract and collate all of the information needed in the action and simply present it to the view.  The view has a simplified set of data that may (or may not) reflect your actual table structure.  I'll update my example based on your structure.